# How can I suppress the "terminate batch job" in cmd.exe

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm looking for a mechanism for suppressing the "Terminate batch job? (Y/N)" invitation that I get whenever I press CTRL-C in a program started from a batch file:

batch file: jsshell.bat:

```
@echo off
java -jar build-scripts\contrib\rhino1.7R1.jar
```

and then starting it on cmd shell by:

```
> jsshell.bat
```

which gives me a shell that can be exited by CTRL-C but after invoking CTRL-C I get a "Terminate batch job (Y/N)?" message which is nasty and annoying. How can I get it to just exit without me having to press 'y'?

Comment: FWIW, this add-on app solves the problem via a setting, and brings much more goodies. https://code.google.com/p/clink/ Can't add as answer since it's closed.

Comment: See also http://superuser.com/questions/35698/how-to-supress-terminate-batch-job-y-n-confirmation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't forget to consider working around the problem by avoiding batch scripts.

- [Doskey macros](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/doskey.mspx?mfr=true) can replace one-liner batch scripts like the one quoted above.  (Load them up in your [Autorun](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779439%28WS.10%29.aspx) script.)
- [Cscript.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490887.aspx) is available on every modern Windows machine and can run JavaScript and VBScript programs from the command line
- If you add file extensions for your favorite scripting language (Perl, Python, Ruby, etc.) to your PATHEXT environment variable and add the script to your path, you can execute them directly without a batch script.

Comment: All good points. However I am aiming for this to work out of the box after stuff is checked out from SVN. So adding things to PATHEXT or autorun doesn't work.

Comment: Your users had to install Java, right?  This is just one more step.

Comment: @cellcortex: Note also that VBScript is already in Pathext.

Comment: I realize this is really old, but I found the question so here's a super helpful guide for implementing the first method listed above [Doskey is to Windows as Alias is to Unix](http://ponderingdeveloper.com/2013/05/06/237/).  Pretty much allows you to replicate the Unix command 'alias'.  Good stuff.

Answer (score 27):

At this [site](http://mythinkpond.wordpress.com/2011/06/24/tired-of-terminate-batch-job-yn-try-this/), I finally found an effective solution:

```
script.cmd < nul
```

To not have to type this out every time I made a second script called `script2.cmd` in the same folder with the line above.  You may want to reverse the names.  Works for me, but tested so far on XP only.

Answer (score 18):

The behaviour is implemented in the cmd.exe source code, and isn't possible to turn off without modifying cmd.exe. However you can **[modify cmd.exe to not show the message](http://axil.github.io/patching-cmdexe.html)**.

Comment: holy crap that is some hard core fix.  Surely there has to be a less obtrusive way?

Comment: When's the last time you got your NOOP on?
Okay, not such a good solution if you wanted anyone else to use.

Comment: Thanks, but patching cmd.exe is something I would rather not like to do.

Comment: Doesn't work on Windows 7; cmd.exe has changed substantially.

Comment: @Dan Fabulich Works perfectly well on Windows 7, don't mislead people.

Comment: Here it is - I remember I saw it somewhere - how to do it on Windows 7: http://axil.github.io/patching-cmdexe.html

Comment: @Microsoft, are you listening??

Comment: Someone do this in official Microsoft repo, please

Answer (score 7):

FWIW, piping 'N' as the input for a command worked me for some batch files (but I actually wanted the new window). Maybe it will work for you too.

```
(echo. N)| cmd /c java -jar build-scripts\contrib\rhino1.7R1.jar
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this might cause issues with languages different than English.  Nice workaround though.

Comment: this works great at least on windows 7

Comment: WOW this works gread on my Win10 machine with locale FR, smart and so userfriendly as it is memorized in the history queue as the original command...compared to patching the cmd.exe...

Comment: this should've been the accepted answer

Comment: Oh and another thing, using `(echo N)` (without the `.`) hides the `^C`.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there is more elegant way than patching cmd.exe. Just put START in front of your command. For your example the line would read like: "START java -jar build-scripts\contrib\rhino1.7R1.jar"

Comment: This seems to open a new console window and run inside that.

Comment: use start /B to not get get a new window

Comment: @JonnyLeeds you don't get a new window this way, but then another problem comes up - when you type 'exit' in the original shell window, it just won't close.

Comment: @egor83 How intuitive! its hard to believe how terrible the windows shell is sometimes!

Comment: @Jonny Leeds with `start /B` in addition to suppressing the prompt 'Terminate batch job' and getting a new window you suppress the Ctrl-C too.

Comment: @AntonyHatchkins nightmare.  Its a while since I messed around with this, maybe it just doesn't work at all,  that seems to be what egor says aswell

Comment: @Jonny Leeds I ended up patching cmd.exe as described in WireGuy's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1234629/237105) above

Answer (score 4):

```
@start cmd /c java -jar build-scripts\contrib\rhino1.7R1.jar
@exit
```

this will make only one window

Comment: It will open a new window and close the current one. Slightly different, especially since the new window won't have any of your size settings. Also, you probably meant `/k` since `/c` will close the second window when the program exits, leaving you with no windows at the end.

Comment: How to add WAIT with this command? "start  /WAIT CMD /K" is not working

Answer (score 2):

The modification below suppresses "Terminate batch job? (Y/N)" *and* the new console window:

```
start cmd /c java -jar build-scripts\contrib\rhino1.7R1.jar
```

Comment: Opens a new console window on my machine.  (I'm on win7 but I doubt that makes a difference.)

Comment: Opens 2 new console windows for me

Comment: Hmm, weird. The example that's working for me is for launching a GWT in hosted mode browser:

start cmd /c %JAVA_HOME%/bin/java %JAVA_OPTS% -classpath %CLASSPATH% com.google.gwt.dev.GWTShell %GWT_OPTS%

This launches a console window when you double click on the BAT file but - as I mentioned above - suppresses the Terminate batch job? (Y/N)" on exit and suppresses the launch of an additional console window. Maybe this "rhino" is a console app and thus must run in a console?

Comment: the trick is: `start /b /wait %comspec% /c java ....`

Answer (score 2):

Try this. It does open a new console, but it locks the other one while it's open.

```
@echo off
start /WAIT java -jar build-scripts\contrib\rhino1.7R1.jar
```