# Remove the prompt "Terminate batch job (Y/N)?" in the windows script

Tags: batch-file

When I type Ctrl^C to stop a running windows script (.bat) from the windows command prompt, it gives me a prompt "Terminate batch job (Y/N)?". How can I remove this prompt?

Thanks

Comment: [This](http://mythinkpond.com/2011/06/24/tired-of-terminate-batch-job-yn-try-this/) might help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I suppress the "terminate batch job" in cmd.exe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234571/how-can-i-suppress-the-terminate-batch-job-in-cmd-exe) and of [How can I suppress the “terminate batch job” in Win7 cmd.exe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580598/how-can-i-suppress-the-terminate-batch-job-in-win7-cmd-exe).

Answer (score 0):

This prompt is a system message that is difficult to disable.
You can try adding an `exit` command. I also found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234571/how-can-i-suppress-the-terminate-batch-job-in-cmd-exe) that may help or you could just deal with it.
This prompt is an important safety prompt to make it so that you don't accidentally stop your batch file.