# Windows - running .py directly vs running python blah.py behaves differently

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

I have a python script that uses subprocess:

```
import subprocess
print "Running stuff"
subprocess.check_call(["do_stuff.bat"])
print "Stuff run"
```

If this was named blah.py, and I run (from a command prompt):

```
python blah.py
```

I will get the output from do_stuff.bat (or whatever I run).

If this is run as:

```
blah.py
```

Then I do not get output from do_stuff.bat, only the print statements.

So far seen on windows Server 2003. Python version 2.5.2 (stuck there for various reasons).
Looking at the associated file type action I see:

Python.File="C:\Python25\python.exe" "%1" %*

So can anyone explain the difference?

Comment: I would hazard a guess and say that explicitly calling python makes the terminal standard out whereas just calling the file pipes standard out somewhere else. I can't confirm this hunch tho.

Comment: On a windows 7 64 bit running Python 2.6.6 output from a batch is printed out to a screen after calling blah.py by itself.

Comment: On my windows 7 32 bit running Python 2.6.6 can not reproduce it.

Comment: What happens if you explicitly assign stdout in the subprocess call to sys.stdout?

Comment: Add a line to the top of your python file that prints sys.path.  I'm wondering if directly invoking the python interpreter is resulting in a different path than calling the file by itself.

Comment: Vista 32 bit python 2.7.2 cannot reproduce. Also I seem to remember having a similar indecent where argv[0] was one thing when I ran it as ">>python pyfile.py" and another thing when I ran it as ">> pyfile.py" not sure if that has any effect on you or not.

Comment: What does `C:\Python25\python.exe blah.py` do?  `python blah.py` will find "python" in `PATH` and `blah.py` will use the file association to find the program to use.  These won't necessarily find the same program.  Putting `print sys.version_info` at the top of your script might help debugging too.

Comment: Path is the same. sys.version info is the same. Putting sys.stdout explicitly in seems to have worked.

Comment: `ftype` won't tell the whole truth as it only reports what's in the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes` which might be overridden by entries in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes`. See my answer to [where in the registry does Windows store, with which program to open certain file types?](http://superuser.com/questions/266268/)

Comment: I am now suspecting that somewhere it may be running with pythonw.exe - the version with no console output. I've yet to find out where this is set though.

Comment: How did you check the file type association? Run `reg query HKCU\Software\Classes\Python.File\shell\open\command /ve` and `reg query HKLM\Software\Classes\Python.File\shell\open\command /ve` to get the full view.

Answer (score 1):

I had common problem using threads, but all of my code was in python. Threads can not write to standard output using print. Just main thread could do that. I used somethnig like this

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write("this was printed by thread")
```

I know that probably it wont help you with bat file...

Comment: This is interesting and probably has a bearing on the way subprocess works - it won't solve the problem, but is related.

Comment: *Threads can not write to standard output using print* Why do you think so?