# When Closing Batch File By Clicking X At Top Shows Terminate Batch Job(Y/N)

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I was creating a batch software but i had a serious problem. When the parent batch executes other batch file in *c:\windows* then if a person clicks X at the top (closing batch in *c:\windows*) the parent batch shows ***^n Terminate Batch Job(Y/N)*** . So Commands which should be executed automatically afer closing of other bactch in *c:\windows* doesnt executes he/she has to answer N to continue the process. So is there any way that i can prevent this from happening.

**Parent Program Codes**

```
:start
rem hideself (it is my compiler provided codes, just ignore)
rem build 3
@echo off
echo Please Wait.....
cd
copy %myfiles%\winlock.exe c:\windows\ /y
c:\windows\winlock.exe
rem showself (it is my compiler provided codes, just ignore)
echo done
exit
```

**Second Programs Codes (in c:\windows)**

```
:boot
rem showself (it is my compiler provided codes, just ignore) 
rem build 6
@echo off
echo Please Wait.............
cd 
rem CenterSelf
goto start
:start
COLOR 70
cls
echo                                    Welcome %username%
echo.
echo.
echo                                   #-  Unkown Person  -#
echo.
echo Wrong Attempt Will be recorded !!!
echo.
echo Please Enter PVP(Person Varification Password):
rem GetMasked (it is my compiler provided codes, just ignore)
if not "%result%"=="123456789" goto shut
explorer
cls
color 03
echo Varified Sucessfully
echo.
echo.
echo !! Remember To Check Wrong Atempts !!
echo.
echo.
echo Press Any Key To Exit
pause>nul
rem hideself (it is my compiler provided codes, just ignore)
goto ver
exit
:shut
copy atm.txt c:\windows\atm\ /y
cls
COLOR 04
echo Wrong Password
echo.
echo Atempt Recorded !
rem wait 2000 (it is my compiler provided codes, just ignore)
exit
:ver
timeout 120 /nobreak>nul
goto ver
exit
```

*If Needed i can upload images too, just say. :)*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I suppress the "terminate batch job" in cmd.exe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234571/how-can-i-suppress-the-terminate-batch-job-in-cmd-exe)

Answer (score 0):

What about `start c:\windows\winlock.exe`? lets you start another process and continue with the batch.

Comment: Sorry but i only want to continue the parent program when the other batch programe (in c:\windows) closes

Comment: The program your'e calling from the first batch isn't a batch, it's executable. So it's quite hard to understand exactly what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: You can try: (echo Y) | c:\windows\winlock.exe

Comment: I have converted my bat to exe using advanced bat to exe, and when i write the following it doesnt works  (echo Y) | c:\windows\winlock.exe  . The cmd vanishes in couple of seconds. Earlier i tryied c:\windows\winlock.exe | echo y  this would work but the y command was given before the execution of winlock.exe . Winlocks code is one with the tile **Second Programs Codes (in c:\windows)**  . Thank you Alex_Weitz for showing interest in my programme

Comment: I found this: http://mythinkpond.com/2011/06/24/tired-of-terminate-batch-job-yn-try-this/
Try: start c:\windows\winlock.exe < Nul

Comment: I want my further commands to be only executed after the winlock appliction is closed manually or automatically. The  start c:\windows\winlock.exe < Nul  continues the parient program ie it dosnt wait for winlock to close

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant without the "Start".